# Add Ounces (oz) option to mass unit setting in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I need Ounces mass unit in product shipping settings. In Products->Shipping there are 5 fields about product shipping. One of them is Package weight. And I need that field to be in ounces, not kilos not pounds. This is due to FedEx with calculating its cost based on ounces. I can convert the weight in code, however, the administrator has to do it by hand.

In Settings->E-commerce, there is a DropDown setting named mass unit. Unfortunately there are only kilos and pounds. I need a way to add ounces option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to modify the values in Modules > E-Commerce > Settings. Not sure of any negative effects that will have, but if you only want to change the values, that would be the place to do it.

Think you might have to change the resource in the database to be able to modify the settings. I think setting the resourceIsindevelopment in CMS_Resource will do it.

Comment: That did the trick. I manually changed resourceIsindevelopment value of ecommerce in CMS_Resource to true and was able to change any settings. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Kentico are you using? You could use the [FedEx Connector for Kentico](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/e-commerce/fedex-connector-for-kentico) in order to calculate live rates.